# `bundler install` throwing GemNoutFound error while `bundle install` works fine on same Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, dependency-management

I have am trying to run `bundler` and/or `bundle` commands against a Gemfile.

Whenever I try any of the `bundler` commands, it throws an error. For example, if I run `bundler install`, I get the following error

**Could not find gem `gem_name` in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.**

But if I run any of the `bundle` commands, like `bundle install`, it will execute successfully. And I cannot figure out the reason behind this..

So here is what my Gemfile looks like.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'byebug'
```

Here is my `bundler env` output.

```
## Environment

Bundler 2.0.2
   Platforms ruby, x86_64-darwin-18
Ruby      2.6.3.p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
   Full Path /path/to/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby
   Config Dir /path/to/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/etc

RubyGems  3.0.4
   Gem Home   /path/to/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
   Gem Path   /path/to/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3:/path/to/home/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global
   User Path  /path/to/home/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
   Bin Dir    /path/to/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin
Tools
   Git    2.20.1 (Apple Git-118)
   RVM    1.29.9 (latest)
   rbenv  not installed
   chruby not installed
   rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)

.. some other info and no Gemfile.lock found since I don't have it yet
```

My `bundle env` output is obviously the same as above.

So I did a lot of digging around `bundler` source code and figured some things out.

When I run `bundle lock`, I eventually reach the file `ruby_executable_hooks.rb` in `Bin Path` above.

Then `Gem::ExecutableHooks.run($0)` gets run and eventually reaches the file `noexec.rb` which returns to `ruby_executable_hooks.rb` saying
**Noexec - skipped binary: bundle**.
Note here that no @index is set for `Bundler::Definition` object, since we never move out of the file `noexec.rb`. This is because we never get past the if-check that reads
`if %w(bundle rubygems-bundler-uninstaller).includes?(bin)`.

Now the control will move down `ruby_executable_hooks.rb` and run
`eval content, binding, $0` and try to run the command. This time, @allowed_remote is true in `rubygems.rb` and Bundler::Index instances actually communicate with remote `rubygems.org` to get the info it is looking for.
After that things go smoothly and `Gemfile.lock` is generated.

But when I run `bundler lock`, things start out the same until we reach `noexec.rb`. Here we get past the if check that ended the flow for `bundle lock` and call the `setup` method defined in `noexec.rb`, which calls the `candidate?` method. This dispatches the control flow to `specs` method defined in `definition.rb`.

It follows the same flow that `bundle lock` went through in its `eval...` call, except that now we entered `specs` method straight without calling `resolve_remotely!`, which sets the @allowed_remote instance variable to `true` for `Bundler::Source` objects.

So when `specs` method of `rubygems.rb` is called as `source.specs` inside `index` method of `defintion.rb`, we are not allowed to fetch things remotely and add them to the Bundler::index object.

Eventually, calling `search` method on the index object doesn't return what it would for `bundle lock` and we never make it past `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found` method in `resolver.rb`. This method raises the exact error statement I put above near line 280-ish in `resolver.rb`. When it is raised, we return to `ruby_executable_hooks` again.

Then we go the `eval..` route as `bundle lock` command did. This time, `@allow_remote` is `true`. But we are prevented from modifying @index variable inside `index` method defined in `definition.rb` because it is already built in the previous run. We never make it past the code
`@index ||= Index.build do ..` since @index is not `nil`.

Rest is the same as our first run that got stopped at `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found`.

I am very confused because I always thought `bundler` just loads `bundle` bin and takes the same route from there. But apparently that is not the case and there are indeed subtle differences.

Am I not setting something correctly in my environment? Please help!

Comment: Why are you using `bundler` command?

Comment: Should i always use bundle? Any reason from the bundler team provided? @MichaelKosyk

Comment: ?? The documentation states that you should use the command `bundle` not `bundler` so there is no reason to use `bundler`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `bundler` - use `bundle`. It's in the Bundler documentation, on the landing page of their site.

Comment: i only see that it says `bundle install` in their example, nowhere it says don't use `bundler install`

Comment: Hmm, how do you think technical documentation works?